# How do I set up ftp users with vsftpd, and have multiple directory locations?

Tags: server, ftp, vsftpd

I'm coming from a Windows environment and have setup a Ubuntu server for the first time, and for the most part I'm doing well, following guides and slowly learning Linux.

But I'm stuck after following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Everything works as expected and I can have users `ftp` into `home/USERNAME/fpt/files`, but I want to also have a way to create `ftp` users for `/var/www/somesite.com/html/`, and I've tried every which configuration and guide, but they all either setup a home directory `ftp`, or a `www/html` directory for ftp, they don't mix them.

On Windows, I create ftp users, and then decide which folder they have access to via folder picker. So what do I need to do to my `vsftpd` config file to create users for for `home/fpt` and `www/somesite`?

Here is my configuration file so far:

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
```

I hope this is the right place to ask this.